# Laravel 5.2, Entrust, 'role_user' table not updating

Tags: php, laravel, entrust

So I'm working with Laravel 5.2 and [Entrust](https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust) package to manage roles/permissions

I'm building a function which should add a user to the 'users' table simultaneously add a relationship to the 'role_user' table. I'm passing an array from a multi_select and then attaching that to a user.

It adds the user to the 'users' table perfectly, but does not add the relationship in the 'role_user' table. I would love some help figuring out what is wrong.

**The part of the form in question:**

```
{!! Form::select('roles[]', $roles, null, ['multiple' => 'multiple', 'class' => 'select-width-100 form-control roles']) !!}
```

**My StoreUser function**

```
public function StoreUser(Request $request)
{

    $input = Request::all();
    $user = New User;
    $user->name = $input['username'];
    $user->email = $input['email'];
    $user->password = Hash::make($input['password']);

    $roles = $input['roles'];
    foreach ($roles as $role)
    {
        $role_id = Role::where('name', $role)->first();
        $user->roles()->attach($role_id);
    }
    $user->save();
    return redirect('/settings/users');

}
```

**Below is my User.php Model**

```
<?php

namespace App;
use Zizaco\Entrust\Traits\EntrustUserTrait;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{

    use EntrustUserTrait;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];
}
```

Comment: If you have an answer, please post it below as an answer so you can mark it "accepted".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Managed to fix it.
I should be looking for 'id' instead of 'name', so this:

```
foreach ($roles as $role)
{
    $role_id = Role::where('name', $role)->first();
    $user->roles()->attach($role_id);
}
```

Should be this:

```
foreach ($roles as $role)
        {
            $role_id = Role::where('id', $role)->first();
            $user->roles()->attach($role_id);
        }
```